# Set minimum date in date picker selected from another date picker

Tags: android, datepicker, mindate

I have two date picker one is arrival date and other is departure date.
what i want is when user opens departure date picker it should have +1 day as the minimum date in this date picker dialog.

Here is what i am doing

This is my arrival date picker

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            arivalYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            arivalMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            arivalDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            arivalDay = year;
                            arivalYear = monthOfYear;
                            arivalMonth = dayOfMonth;

                            arivalDateTV.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, arivalYear, arivalMonth, arivalDay);
            dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            dpd.show();
```

Here is my departure date picker

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            departureYear = year;
                            departureMonth = monthOfYear;
                            departureDay = dayOfMonth;

                            departureDateTV.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, arivalYear, arivalMonth, arivalDay);
            Date min = new Date();
            min.setDate(arivalDay);
            min.setMonth(arivalMonth);
            min.setYear(arivalYear);

            dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(min.getDate());
            dpd.show();
```

But here i can even select the dates before the arrival date.
What i am doing wrong.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Could you log the `arivalDay`, `arivalMonth`, `arivalYear` before setting to `min`?

Comment: Also the min.setDate(arivalDay) is probably incorrect. It should be something like setDay instead of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably assigning wrong values to `arivalDay`, `arivalMonth` and `arivalYear`.

Inside your arrival date picker, check your `onDateSet()` method.

The following lines are probably incorrect (you are assigning the selected year to `arivalDay`, the selected month to `arivalYear`, and selected day to `arivalMonth`).

```
arivalDay = year;
arivalYear = monthOfYear;
arivalMonth = dayOfMonth;
```

Should be:

```
arivalDay = dayOfMonth;
arivalYear = year;
arivalMonth = monthOfYear;
```

Also `setDate(int day)` is deprecated.

> This method was deprecated in API level 1. Use
>   Calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day) instead.

Answer (score 1):

For departure min date You are setting the same as arrival date.
instead of

```
min.setDate(arivalDay);
```

try this

```
min.setDate(arivalDay +1);
```

and while setting it in arrival listener instead of this

```
arivalDay = year;
arivalYear = monthOfYear;
arivalMonth = dayOfMonth;
```

it should be

```
arivalDay = dayOfMonth;
arivalYear = year;
arivalMonth = monthOfYear;
```